# undeclared identifier 'byte'. compile C code

Tags: c, xcode

I'm trying to compile library from .c file in Xcode. (It doesn't give me any errors in Visual Studio on Windows) But Xcode gives:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'byte'

in the next line:

```
buf[2] = (byte)(addr & 0xff);
```

Comment: `byte` is not a standard `C` type. So it has to be defined somewhere in the code which we have no idea about.

Comment: You should include the relevant header file that defines the type `byte`

Comment: In Visual Studio is the original program in C# or C? C# has a `byte` type, but not C. You need to think more carefully about what you're doing.

Comment: are you shure this isn't for example Java... or C#...

Comment: What is the type of `buf[2]`, and why don't you cast to that type?

Comment: unsigned char buf[256];

Comment: I'm sure that it's C not c#

Comment: Please take the [tour], review [Ask] and [MCVE].  If you then edit your question to meet SO standards, the question might lose some of down-votes or maybe pick-up an up-vote.  Often, by the time you go through the effort of producing an MCVE, you resolve the problem on your own.

Comment: If the type of buf[2] is char, then why is it being cast to byte?

Comment: *I'm sure that it's C not c#*. That doesn't change the fact that `byte` is not part of standard C. It's obvious that the error means that C doesn't know what `byte` is. Maybe in Visual Studio you have a `typedef unsigned char byte;` somewhere. You could add that to your code, or use `buf[2] = (unsigned char)(addr & 0xff);` to alleviate your troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .c file i have declared `byte` with the next code:

```
typedef uint8_t byte
```

uint8_t is similar to byte, so it compiled